# Calling SSIS from a .aspx page, what permissions to give to NT AUTH\Network Service account?

Tags: .net, ssis

When I call a SSIS package using LoadPackage() from a .aspx page (or windows service), how do I setup permissions for it to work?

Event viewer is reporting a Sql server error:

Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: 192.168.73.118]

How do I give that account access to my sql server?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should change permissions for NETWORK SERVICE. That will increase the security risks of your Sql Server, as compromise of ASP.NET or any other service running as NETWORK SERVICE will compromise Sql Server. There are also reliability issues with running SSIS inside ASP.NET process.

I would suggest to run SSIS outside of ASP.NET process, using some specific user account.

See some ideas on various ways to run SSIS programmatically:
http://blogs.msdn.com/michen/archive/2007/03/22/running-ssis-package-programmatically.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Grant it access http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998320.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you running a non-english Operation System?

For some reasons, some account names like "NT Authority\Network Service" has been localized in other languages.
Sadly, a lot of programs have the account names hard coded to the english names, and won't find the account when running on foreign versions of Windows.